# Adding custom code to an Entity Framework Class

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I have a question about programming practices regarding entity framework classes.

When I create the .edmx file, it creates the class, but when I update this file, all methods I made for the this class are gone.

My question is: Should I create another class, that contains all the methods? In this case, the entity framework class would only have attributes?

Comment: Please check my edit, I tried to clean up what you were talking about

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Entity Framework (Model-First) generates a code file for you. **Any changes you make to that file will be lost the next time it is generated**. There's even a warning to that effect in a comment at the top of the file.

*However*, those classes are marked `partial` (as most generated classes are) so you can have a separate code file that contains the remainder of the class definition (ie, your methods). See MSDN for more information on [partial classes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488.aspx).

You can also write other classes that take the data objects as parameters. This is *usually* how you do this, as EF objects are typically left data-only.